# Composer doesn't run in presence of composer.json

Tags: composer-php

I installed composer globally on my Debian server

```
~$ which composer
/usr/local/bin/composer
```

It works, gets updated and I used it for three different (Symfony) sites.

```
~$ composer self-update
You are already using composer version 1.3.3 (stable channel).
```

However, when I am in the directory of one of the sites, and try to update all dependencies, I get an error (before, this just worked and updated the vendors etc).

```
~/website-path$ ls composer.*
composer.json  composer.lock

~/website-path$ composer update

  [ErrorException]
  Illegal string offset 'version'

~/website-path$ composer

  [ErrorException]
  Illegal string offset 'version'
```

When I rename composer.json, this Error disappears (but the lack of .json file makes this quite useless)

**What went wrong here and how can I fix this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem magically went away overnight by upgrading to 1.4.0

```
~$ composer -V
Composer version 1.4.0 2017-03-08 17:51:24

~/website-path$ composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
[...]
```